# property promotion in infopath and sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath-2007

I have a SharePoint 2010 document library with >7000 xml documents created from infopath forms(Infopath 2007). Now i would like to promote few fields in the form to the SharePoint document library. I could do this only for documents created from the upgraded form, but not for all previously created documents. Although re submitting of old forms will work,It is not possible for me to update all 7000 records to promote the values to the column. Is there a much easier solution, considering the fact that this changes need to be implemented on a production environment too.

Note:The promoted columns will be used to generate graphical report. Any solution acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through this before, and there's no good answer. If I understand correctly, you have existing InfoPath forms in a doc library, and you now want to promote fields to the document library, but you don't want to open each form one by one, correct?

Note, you most likely don't have to open then re-submit each form, you just have to open the form, and close it. Once you do that, the promoted fields will them show up.

So... what I've done before is this:  First, get notepad++ (this allows you to open multiple files in tabs). Secondly, access the the doc library via WebDav (that is, go to the library in SharePoint, then go to the Library tab, and click Open with Explorer). Thirdly, open a large batch of files at once using notepad++ (select files, right-click, open with notepad++). It will take a moment for all the files to load in notepad++ in tabs. Once they are all open in notepad++, hit ctrl-w as fast as you can (which closes each file).  Rinse and repeat.

It's not pretty, and I'm sure there's a better way to do this (programatically, perhaps), but this should work. At least you won't have to open each form one by one.

Comment: Thanks but i have lots of nested folders and doing this for all 7000 records seems to be a far cry! I have added a note to my question describing the purpose - I would probably go with running a batch that would iterate over all forms and update the column, but this would change all my 'modified by' fields by System Account! As this will be a report, I am planning to convert the form data into excel for all old documents that were created before the form upgrade.

Comment: I found that on SharePoint 2010 at least, it's enough to just open the library in windows explorer and as the file icon changes from blank pages to infopath icons, (it takes a little while) it re-populates the promoted properties . No need to open in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by relinking the document by powershell or through advanced settings.

Comment: Please provide an explanation on how to link it with powershell, or how to use advanced settings.